# Atomic Reference Counting

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, reference-counting

I'm trying to understand exactly how thread-safe, atomic reference counting works, for example as with `std::shared_ptr`.  I mean, the basic concept is simple, but I'm really confused about how the decref plus `delete` avoids race conditions.

This [tutorial from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html#boost_atomic.usage_examples.example_reference_counters) demonstrates how an atomic thread-safe reference counting system can be implemented using the Boost atomic library (or the C++11 atomic library).

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>

class X {
public:
  typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<X> pointer;
  X() : refcount_(0) {}

private:
  mutable boost::atomic<int> refcount_;
  friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(const X * x)
  {
    x->refcount_.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_relaxed);
  }
  friend void intrusive_ptr_release(const X * x)
  {
    if (x->refcount_.fetch_sub(1, boost::memory_order_release) == 1) {
      boost::atomic_thread_fence(boost::memory_order_acquire);
      delete x;
    }
  }
};
```

Okay, so I get the general idea.  But I don't understand why the following scenario is NOT possible:

Say the refcount is currently `1`.

1. *Thread A*: atomically decrefs the refcount to `0`.
2. *Thread B*: atomically increfs the refcount to `1`.
3. *Thread A*: calls `delete` on the managed object pointer.
4. *Thread B*: sees the refcount as `1`, accesses the managed object pointer... **SEGFAULT!**

I can't understand what prevents this scenario from occurring, since there is nothing preventing a data race from *between* the time the refcount reaches 0, and the object is deleted.  Decrefing the refcount and calling `delete` are two separate, non-atomic operations.  So how is this possible without a lock?

Comment: How does the refcount is 1 while there are two references from the two threads?

Comment: You need to spell out the invariant of a use count. A use count should never reach 0 while there are users. Your code must have a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 30):

You probably overestimate the threadsafety a shared_ptr provides.

The essence of atomic ref counting is to ensure that if **two different instances** of a `shared_ptr` (that are managing the same object) are accessed/modified, there will be no race condition. However, `shared_ptr` doesn't ensure thread safety, if two threads access the same `shared_ptr` object (and one of them is a write). One example would be e.g. if one thread dereferences the pointer, while the other resets it.
So about the only thing `shared_ptr` gurantees is that there will be no double delete and no leak as long as there is no race on a single instance of a shared_ptr  (It also doesn't make accesses to the object it points to threadsafe)

As a result, also creating a copy of a shared_ptr is only safe, if there is no other thread that could delete/reset it at the same time (you could also say, it is not internally synchronized). This is the scenario you describe.

To repeat it once more: Accessing a **single** `shared_ptr` **instance** from **multiple threads**  where one of those accesses is a write to the pointer **is still a race condition**.

If you want to e.g. copy a `std::shared_ptr`in a threadsafe manner, you have to ensure that all loads and stores happen via [`std::atomic_...`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) operations which are specialized for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Atomic operations on `shared_ptr` are little known and underrated. +1

Comment: @sehe: A more accurate description is that "atomic operations on shared pointers are horribly misdesigned and broken" :-) Efforts are underway to improve that situation, though.

Comment: @sehe: I have to admit that I haven't used them myself, yet. I only remembered them from Herb Sutter's talk about lock-free programming at cppcon2014.

Comment: I used them. But they aren't widely supported yet. Also, the standard doesn't require the implementation to actually use atomics.

Comment: Does this also apply to QSharedPointer? Qt documentation states that "QSharedPointer and QWeakPointer are thread-safe and operate atomically on the pointer value. "

Comment: @philipp: As you said yourself, all methods of QSharedPointer are threadsafe. So the above answer doesn't apply to it, but only to std::shared_ptr (and I believe also to the boost version). Actually, my impression is that most things in QT work differently than in the STL.

Comment: For the record, the presentation at ccpcon2014, mentioned by @MikeMB, can be found at https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/Lock-Free%20Programming%20%28or%2C%20Juggling%20Razor%20Blades%29/Lock-Free%20Programming%20%28or%2C%20Juggling%20Razor%20Blades%29%20-%20Herb%20Sutter%20-%20CppCon%202014.pdf But it does not directly answer this point, AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinQuinson: I only mentioned it as the reason, why I was aware of those specializations at all (although I still haven't used them). What point exactly would you would you like to have answered? Maybe I can oblige

Comment: I'm currently fighting against a similar bug, and found the presentation interesting (even if not perfect), thus the posting as comment.

Answer (score 4):

Your scenario is not possible because Thread B should have been created with an incremented refcount already. Thread B should not be incrementing the ref count as the first thing it does.

Let's say Thread A spawns Thread B. Thread A has the responsibility to increment the ref count of the object BEFORE creating the thread, to guarantee thread safety. Thread B then only has to call release when it exits.

If Thread A creates Thread B without incrementing the ref count, bad things might happen as you've described.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question you've answered?

Comment: @IInspectable: Seems like a perfectly reasonable answer to the question on this page - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

> Thread B: atomically increfs the refcount to 1.

Impossible. To increment the reference count to one, the reference count would have to be zero. But if the reference count is zero, how is thread B accessing the object at all?

Either thread B has a reference to the object or it doesn't. If it does, then the reference count cannot be zero. If it does not, then why is it messing with an object managed by smart pointers when it has no reference to that object?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation doesn't provide or require such a guarantee, avoidance of the behavior you are describing is predicated on the proper management of counted-references, usually done through a RAII class such as `std::shared_ptr`. The key is to entirely avoid passing by raw pointer across scopes. Any function which stores or retains a pointer to the object must take a shared pointer so that it can properly increment the ref count.

```
void f(shared_ptr p) {
   x(p); // pass as a shared ptr
   y(p.get()); // pass raw pointer
}
```

This function was passed a `shared_ptr` so the refcount was already 1+. Our local instance, `p`, should have bumped the ref_count during copy-assignment. When we called `x` if we passed by value we created another ref. If we passed by const ref, we retained our current ref count. If we passed by non-const ref then it's feasible that `x()` released the reference and `y` is going to be called with null.

If `x()` stores/retains the raw pointer, then we may have a problem. When our function returns the refcount might reach 0 and the object might be destroyed. This is our fault for not correctly maintaining ref count.

Consider:

```
template<typename T>
void test()
{
    shared_ptr<T> p;
    {
        shared_ptr<T> q(new T); // rc:1
        p = q; // rc:2
    } // ~q -> rc:1
    use(p.get()); // valid
} // ~p -> rc:0 -> delete
```

vs

```
template<typename T>
void test()
{
    T* p;
    {
        shared_ptr<T> q(new T); // rc:1
        p = q; // rc:1
    } // ~q -> rc:0 -> delete
    use(p); // bad: accessing deleted object
}
```

Comment: Still, this can be a problem by just using the shared pointers assignment operator. I came into such a situation I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918932/what-is-the-cost-of-calling-member-function-via-shared-pointer

Answer (score 1):

For `std::shared_ptr` a reference counting change is thread safe, but not the access to the content of the `shared_ptr.

Regarding `boost::intrusive_ptr<X>`, this is no answer.