# How are atomic reference counts propagated to all copies of all class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, reference-counting

I try to understand how atomic reference counting works but fail to grasp how reference counts propagate to all copies of an instance. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254767/atomic-reference-counting) and on the [boost reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html) I constructed the following code:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
struct X {
    X() : ref_cout_(1){};
    mutable std::atomic<int> ref_cout_;
    X(const X* other) {
        other->ref_cout_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    };
    ~X() {
        if (ref_cout_.fetch_sub(1) == 1) {
            std::cout << "relese main ressource " << std::endl;
        };
    }
    void print() { std::cout << ref_cout_.load() << std::endl; };
};

int main() {
    X* first = new X();
    X* second = new X(first); //ref count of first = 2; as expected
    X* third = new X(second);  // ref count does not seem to propagate to first
    first->print(); //prints :2. Strange
};
```

In this code above, the reference count of `first` is `1`, then `2`, and then still `2`. For proper reference counting to work, I expected that creating object `third` would increase the reference count of all copies to three. I have thus the following questions:

- How can I implement a reference counting facility that increases the reference count of all copies?
- Why does the class use `std::atomic<int>` as reference count, and not `std::atomic<int*>?

I am grateful for all hints and suggestions!

Comment: That `mutable` isn't needed. `std::atomic` takes care of it.

Comment: Each object has its own copy of `ref_cout_`, so copying `second` to make `third` doesn't affect `first`. Forget the `atomic` here -- it doesn't affect what this code does. If you need to share values between threads, you need to share them, not make separate copies.

Comment: `mutable std::atomic<int> ref_cout_;` probably should be `std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<int>> ref_cout_;`.  (And there is some irony there.)

Comment: @Eljay just `static std::atomic<int> ref_cout_;` would do ?

Comment: @RichardCritten • Possibly, depending on fabian's use case.

Comment: This is not how reference-counting works, on a fundamental level.